# Making Spring Boot start lazy generates tons of warnings by CachingModelPropertiesProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lazy-initialization

To speed up my manual smoke testing I configured my environment to boot lazy, with:

```
spring.main.lazy-initialization=true
```

It actually works fine by cutting 1/3 of my applications starting time.

However upon start my application log is filled with rows like:

> WARN  s.d.schema.property.CachingModelPropertiesProvider.propertiesFor:66 - Exception calculating properties for model

Searched for the reason and how to get rid of these but only suggestion found was not to use lazy initialization.

While everything still seems to work fine when using lazy initialization should I worry about these messages or can I just ignore and maybe suppress those rows?

And if I can suppress those is there a preferred/correct method for example to skip the phase that generates those messages or should I just configure it in my logger?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known issue, please see https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2992.

Since they are related to Springfox one possible workaround could be to try using https://springdoc.org/ to generate swagger documentation.

Comment: Thanks. This is quite the same I found myself so there seems not to be clear solution with springfox, yet.